# Array changing doesnt work

Tags: java, regex

Array doesn't change after running this code. 
What is the reason of it? 
Thank you

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] h = new String[100];
    int hlds = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        if(s.hasNextLine()) {

            String str = s.nextLine();

            if (Pattern.matches("[abc]", str)) {
                h[hlds++] = str;
            }
            for( int i = 0; i < h.length ; i++){
                System.out.println(h[i]);
            }
            break;
            }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: I need to write down strings in array , which contain letters abc

Comment: Probably because `if (Pattern.matches("[abc]", str))` is never met.

Comment: So, how i need to change it?

Comment: I have updated my answer, so you want strings which contains letter a, b, or c in the input line.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.matches("[abc]", str)
```

Evaluates to true only if you enter either `a` or `b` or `c`

because of the regex you have used `[abc]`, see the docs about [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

If you enter `ab` then it would not be accepted.

If you want your input to contain any of the char then you could change your regex to `[abc]+`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `[abc]` means "a single character either a, b or c".

Change your regex to `[abc]+`, meaning "one or more characters either a, b or c"

Answer (score 0):

(updated after reading all comments...)

Okey, so if I understand it right:
You want to store into the array from input line those who contains a, b or c letters.

apple, ball, catch, table, tictac... will be stored. Right?

I would use the String contains, or indexof to fins a, b, and c letters. This is more efficient that regex.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String [] h = new String[10];

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(a|b|c)");
for(int hlds=0; hlds<h.length;hlds++ ) {
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    String str = s.nextLine();
    /* with regex
    if( p.matcher(str).find() ) {
        h[hlds] = str;
    }
    */

    /* with contains */
    if( str.contains("a") || str.contains("b") || str.contains("c") ) {
        h[hlds] = str;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(h));
```

Comment: The loop is ok, but OP wants strings that match a pattern, not that  all are equal to `abc` and ending with an array of 100 `abc`s.

Comment: No. I'm just trying to find strings, which contain a, b or c and write them down to an array.

Answer (score 0):

**Extra Info:**
This would also work:

```
str.matches("[abc]+");
```

It calls `Pattern.matches(regex,this);` internally. (where `regex` is the regular expression used)